# Retrieve data from DbContext with strings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

With Entity Framework you can easily get data from the database doing something like this:

```
var allBooks = BookContext.Books;
```

So this code returns all books from the "Book" table.

But I'm getting a string back that tells me from what "table" I need the data from. So I have something like this:

```
public void GetData(string entity) // entity = "Book"
{
    // Get data using the "entity" string from BookContext
    BookContext.FromString(entity); // for exmaple
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve data from the `BookContext` using a string?

Comment: The possible duplicate applies to EF6, this question is about EF7.

Comment: @GertArnold That's true. But I think the answer also works for EF7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look to the [source code of EF7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbContext.cs) reveals that, in contrast to the previous versions, there isn't any `Set(Type entityType)` method in the `DbContext` class. There is only the it's generic version `Set<TEntity>()`.

So I think, it isn't possible without using some *obscure* reflection. (*Obscure* because EF7 doesn't have any non-generic version of the `DbSet` class which makes working with the set obtained by the reflection quite difficult)